# Почему функция length() в SQL выводит неправильное количество символов если символы русские?

Tags: mysql, sql

Почему функция length() в SQL выводит неправильное количество символов если символы русские? Если символы латинские то всё верно но если русские то вывод неверный.
[image: Вывод Select]

Поменял кодировку и самой БД и таблицы на utf8 - не помогло.

[image: Кодировка БД]

Я только изучаю SQL, сори если вопрос тупой но на просторах интернета ответа не нашёл как это исправить.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Функция `length()` в MySQL возвращает длину строки в байтах. А Русские символы в кодировке UTF-8 занимают 2 байта.

Для получения длины строки в символах надо использовать функцию `char_length()`

Comment: Спасибо большое!